# Is it possible to show same page with different url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I want to show same content for different URL. For example:

```
website.com/controllername/country/state1/dist1/
website.com/controllername/country/state2/dist2/
```

I want these two URL to show same content.Even though the some content will vary based on URL (like name of state and district). I don't want to create separate content/page for every URL. I want to know if its possible to do so in Codeigniter? and is it possible to show a URL like the above in Codeigniter?

Comment: I guess you want same `view` file with two different `routes`

Comment: Yes, it should be, that's kind of the whole point of this kind of URL pattern. It all depends on setting up your routing rules etc. I'm sure you can study this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with Codeigniter routing,

In your `application/config/routes.php` paste the below code and change the controller and function name you used,

`$route['([a-zA-Z0-9---_%])+/([a-zA-Z0-9---_%])+/([a-zA-Z0-9---_%])'] = 'your_controller_name/your_function_name/$1/$1/$1';`

Comment: IN this routing all pages which have 2 parameter accessing same pages.  Its not good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other frameworks CodeIgniter does not have a global template system. Each Controller controls it's own output independent of the system and views are FIFO unless otherwise specified.

For instance if we have a global header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" >
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$title?></title>
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <?=$javascript ?>
        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <?=$css ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <!-- Logos, menus, etc... -->
        </div>
        <div id="content">
```

and a global footer:

```
</div>
        <div id="footer">
            <!-- Copyright, sitemap, links, etc... -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

then our controller would have to look like

```
class Welcome extends Controller {

    function index() {
        $data['title'] = 'My title';
        // Javascript, CSS, etc...

        $this->load->view('header', $data);

        $data = array();
        // Content view data
        $this->load->view('my_content_view', $data);

        $data = array();
        // Copyright, sitemap, links, etc...
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set same page with different url setting on routing.
Refer below link for more info:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

$route['controllername/country/state1/dist1/'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';
$route['controllername/country/state1/dist2/'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';

Answer (score 0):

Improving the krishnaraj answer...

you need 
website.com/controllername/method1/st/dist/ 
website.com/controllername/method2/st/dist/

//i´ve changed some variables for better understanding, and the "country" would
//be the main change

so at your controller you just

```
public function method1($st1,$st2){ 
     $this->load->view('header');

     $this->load->model('data_processing');
     $data['data'] = $this->data_processing->any_model_function($st1,$st2);

     $this->load->view('page_you_want',$data);
     //here you choose the same view for both methods

     $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function method2($st1,$st2){ 
     $this->load->view('header');

     $this->load->model('data_processing');
     $data['data'] = $this->data_processing->any_model_function($st1,$st2);

     $this->load->view('page_you_want',$data); 
     //here you choose the same view

     $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

In the case of route configuration explained by Kavin Smk, noticed just a mistake, instead of

```
'your_controller_name/your_function_name/$1/$1/$1';
```

it shoud be

```
'your_controller_name/your_function_name/$1/$2/$3';
```

Well, there is always a lot of ways to do the same, choose yours...
Good luck!