# How to map different url to same page (HTML) Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, css

What I am trying to do is when the user creates some post(social media post) it has a unique id in backend
example 1123 and one more post with unique id of 1134 there is only one html page How and to access them the urls are like this

```
    mysite.com/post/1123------>post.html
    mysite.com/post/1134------>post.html

how do I map these two urls to same page  using javascript.
```

And I dont want to pass the unique ids in parameters because these are the links to specific post that all users can see
Can anybody help me on this

It should be like this
First Post with ID 1123

URL mysite.com/post/1123

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>hello id 1123</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and the next post(social media post)  with id 1134

URL mysite.com/post/1134

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>hello id 1134</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And these two URL's are pointing to same html

Comment: I guess you are getting these two numbers over some action can you please explain more like are you trying to generating dynamic URL in the main page or how these two URLs you will get and how they will called?

Comment: like in stackoverflow when you post some question it has a url like  questions/uniqueId/nameOfQuestion  and it has many question so they will not create html page for each question what they will do is create one html and map it to different url and urls example I have given in question .what I want is diferent questions have different url but they all map to single html page

Comment: Please have a look https://jsfiddle.net/niteshsharma/ec7fa5q2/7/ not sure but might help you or give you some idea

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is only possible using your hosting service if it supports routing. Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45998266/8062035).